# Deleting Documents Directory iphone

Tags: cocoa-touch

What would be the quickest way to delete the contents in the documents directory. 
I have a list of the contents loaded into an NSArray but I'm not sure of the objective c on how to delete safely. I've googled for a solution but cant seem to find anything.
Thanks for your help.
PS, can you recommend a good book for Begginners on iphone programming
Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically, you want NSFileManager's `-(BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error` this is documented in the SDK.

There aren't many iPhone programming books but I think Dave Mark and Jeff LaMarche's [Beginning iPhone Development: Exploring the iPhone SDK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430216263) is one of the best introductions.

Answer (score 0):

NSFileManager handles all the filesystem operations, including file deletion.